# C preprocessor: what is the rationale behind not allowing argument of the #include directive to begin with a digit?

Tags: c, include, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor, diagnostics

N2479 C17..C2x working draft — February 5, 2020 ISO/IEC 9899:202x (E):

> 6.10.2 Source file inclusion
>
> The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences consisting of one or more nondigits or digits (6.4.2.1) followed by a period (.) and a single nondigit. The first character shall not be a digit.

Question: what is the rationale behind not allowing argument (`char-sequence`) of the `#include` directive to begin with a digit?

Extra question: compilers seem to not generate any diagnostic message when the shall requirement above is violated (ex. use of `#include "1.h"`). Why?

UPD. Later my colleague answered: the `The first character shall not be a digit` is related only to `unique mappings`. So, the standard was misinterpreted.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- what about "_the first character shall not be a digit_"?

Comment: @adabsurdum: Oops, missed that.

Comment: @pmor -- diagnostics are only required for violations of syntax rules and constraints; this is neither, so no diagnostic is required. It is still undefined behavior due to the violation of a "shall" outside of a constraint, though.

Comment: @adabsurdum: There is no violation of a rule here. The paragraph does not say a program may not use such a sequence. The paragraph just allows the implementation to not map it uniquely; “1.h” could map to the same header as “foo.h”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- 6.10.2 5 says that the first character of the _h-char-sequence_ or _q-char-sequence_ "shall not be a digit." Using the _q-char-sequence_ "1.h" violates this shall, so it is undefined behavior by 4 2: "_If a “shall” or “shall not” requirement that appears outside of a constraint...._" Maybe the implementation does not provide a unique mapping for the sequence; maybe it does not provide one at all. Or am I misreading something horribly?

Comment: @adabsurdum: I was interpreting that as a qualification on the mappings the implementation must map uniquely, since the sentence before it and the sentence after it both speak to what the implementation must do with these sequences. It’s a little odd to stick that sentence between them, or in that paragraph at all, if it is restricting what sequences are allowed in header names. The formats of header names are covered in an entirely different clause, 6.4.7, which includes an example of `#include <1/a.h>`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- I agree that it is peculiar. I just looked in Harbison & Steele's _C: A Reference Manual_, and they say "_Standard C requires that all implementations permit file names in `#include` consisting of letters and digits (beginning with a letter)...._" (Ch 3.4, p. 60).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: what is the rationale behind not allowing argument (char-sequence) of the #include directive to begin with a digit?

By itself, the sentence “The first character shall not be a digit” would seem to be saying that a C program shall not use a digit as the first character in a header name. However, it is between two sentences that tell us how C implementations must process header names and is in a clause, 6.10, that tells us how implementations process `#include` directives. The clause that tells us the grammar for header names is in a different place in the C standard, 6.4.7, where it gives `#include <1/a.h>` as an example of a possible directive (C 2018 6.4.7 4).

So I believe the intent of 6.10.2 5 is to provide a quality-of-implementation guarantee, saying that you cannot implement C directly using a file system that does not support at least eight characters in the base part of file names, but you can use a file system that ignores case (per its last sentence) or that does not support names beginning with a digit. Although “The first character shall not be a digit” appears to be a prohibition on C programs, that is because a mistake was made in putting this in a separate sentence without qualification; the first two sentences should have been something like “The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences consisting of a nondigit (6.4.2.1) followed by zero or more nondigits or digits followed by a period (`.`) and a single nondigit.”

(In C 1990, this paragraph appears in 6.8.2, where the significance requirement is only for six characters. It was increased to eight in C 1999, reflecting the prevalence of better file systems.)

Comment: I found [this defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_302.htm) which does suggest the stipulation that a filename must begin with a nondigit in 6.10.2 5 should be interpreted as applying to the uniqueness guarantee.

Comment: Later my colleague answered: the `The first character shall not be a digit` is related only to `unique mappings`.
It seems that the idea was to achieve the minimum set of requirements, which need to be satisfied to achieve portability across all (or almost all) operating systems. However, it seems that the `unique mappings` have a room for improvement: what happens if you try to `#include "con.h"` in `msvc` under Windows?

Comment: If `#include <1/a.h>` is an example of a possible directive, then why it is UB when "The character sequence in an #include preprocessing directive does not start with a letter (6.10.2)" (J.2 Undefined behavior)?

Comment: Note: I understand "The first character shall not be a digit" as a requirement for sequence _produced by the mapping_.

Comment: However, if a C compiler maps `0.h` (for example) to `0.h` (i.e. one-to-one), then it violates the "The first character shall not be a digit" (after mapping). So, finally this requirement is related to the sequence "before mapping" or "after mapping"?

Comment: @pmor: Re “If `#include <1/a.h>` is an example of a possible directive, then why it is UB when "The character sequence in an #include preprocessing directive does not start with a letter (6.10.2)" (J.2 Undefined behavior)?”: Because doing something that has undefined behavior is allowed.

Comment: @pmor: Re “Later my colleague answered: the ‘The first character shall not be a digit’ is related only to unique mappings.”: Yes, that is what this answer states, as “the first two sentences should have been something like “The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences consisting of a nondigit (6.4.2.1) followed by zero or more nondigits or digits followed by a period (`.`) and a single nondigit.”” The statement that the first character should be a nondigit was meant to be part of the prequisites for unique mappings.

Comment: @pmor: Re “I understand "The first character shall not be a digit" as a requirement for sequence *produced by the mapping*.”: No. It is a requirement to qualify for the guarantee that the mapping is unique. All sequences consisting of one or more nondigits or digits followed by a period and a single nondigit that start with a nondigit will be mapped to some uniquely identified file.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So why `1.h` is not guaranteed to be mapped to some uniquely identified file? It can be mapped to `zzz1.h` (for example).