# Can a header file name start with a digit?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, header-files

Can a header file name start with a digit? Is there a situation where this can be dangerous?

```
#include "01_HeaderA.hpp"
#include "02_HeaderB.hpp"
```

I need this when implementing message classes with unique IDs.

Comment: Yes it can. Note that it's quite uncommon though.

Comment: Can? Yes (source: try it). Dangerous? No (source: ???). As long as the file name fits into the file system constraints (it does, unless you use ancient 8.3 msdos scheme) and is representable in the source file charset (numbers are ascii, no problem there) you should be fine.

Comment: C++ does not care what kind of filenames are allowed and what not. This depends on the operating system (and perhaps filesystem as well).

Comment: From what I remember, "header files" do not even need to be actual files.

Comment: @teapot418 dangerous - yes. Imagine you want to compile this program on the computer which does not support file names starting with numbers

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35977940/valid-characters-for-file-name-in-the-include-directive

Comment: Practically, it can if your operating system (or file system) supports such filenames.   Formally, the behaviour (e.g. how the preprocessor finds the contents of an `#include`d file) is implementation-defined.   Personally, I'd probably have headers such as `Msg01.h`, `Msg02.h` rather than `01Msg`, `02Mge.h` but that's a stylistic concern, not [if your target system supports such file names] a technical one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corrected based on comment from Eric Postpischil:

This is allowable by the C standard.  The C standard supports all alphanumeric digits and 29 additional characters.

Section 6.10.2, paragraph 5 of the C standard (C99 - C17) states:

> The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences consisting of one or more nondigits or digits (6.4.2.1) followed by a period (.) and a single nondigit. The first character shall not be a digit. The implementation may ignore distinctions of alphabetical case and restrict the mapping to eight significant characters before the
> period.

The compiler may "allow" a program to be built with a leading digit, but the behavior may not be portable between systems and should not be used.

Note that this rule is in contradiction with Section 6.4.7, paragraph 4 of the standard (C99 and C17), which provides the following example:

```
#include <1/a.h>
```

Comment: It is allowed by the C standard, but the behavior is not defined by the C standard. C 2018 6.10.2 5 says “The first character shall not be a digit.” When a program violates such a rule in the C standard, the behavior is not defined by the standard.

Answer (score 3):

> Can a header file name start with a digit?

It **may** start with a digit; the C grammar allows for it. However, **the behavior is not defined by the C standard**, as explained below. (The character sequences allowed for header names are defined in C 2018 6.4.7 1, and the rules allow any members of the source character set except newline and `>`.)

Note that although the below explains the C standard as it stands, I think the wording referred to may have been a mistake in drafting the standard, as I discuss in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66185651/298225).

> Is there a situation where this can be dangerous?

Yes, the rules in the C standard for headers do not require names starting with digits to work. C 2018 6.10.2 5 says “**The first character shall not be a digit.**” If this rule is violated, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, per C 2018 4 2.

It also says “The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences consisting of one or more nondigits or digits (6.4.2.1) followed by a period (.) and a single nondigit.” Your names also do not conform to this pattern, as `01_HeaderA.hpp` has three characters after the period. That does not render the behavior undefined by the C standard, but it does mean they do not necessarily map to unique names in the file system.

The paragraph also says “The implementation may ignore distinctions of alphabetical case and restrict the mapping to eight significant characters before the period.”

Most modern C implementations map header file names in source code directly to names in the file system, possibly ignoring case if necessary. In some cases, they may translate the trailing `.h` to something else in a managed library of header files. Not supporting leading digits in the file system is mostly something of older operating systems, so you are unlikely to encounter it today. However, as the C standard does not define the behavior, you cannot rely on it being fully portable.

The C++ standard has similar wording (in C++ 2020 draft N4849, 15.3 [cpp.include] 5.

Answer (score 2):

A header file can have any name supported by your operating/file system

> Is there a situation where this can be dangerous?

Theoretically yes, if you try to compile your program on the machine hosted by the operating system which does not support file names starting with digits. I am not aware of any, but maybe such one exists

Answer (score 1):

The standard says that *the implementation can enforce extra rules to map the names* (which in the source, are properly delimited by double quotes `"` or `<` and `>` characters) and gives some examples of mappings enforced by several systems (old unix systems enforced a path element couldn't be more than 14 characters length, ms-dos systems enforced 8.3 syntax for filenames ---eight characters for name plus three more for the extension---) so, in general, any rule you follow to name include files can be, in some particular way, forbidden by some system.  And because this is something that is permitted by the standard.  So you have to obey the rules of your installation to avoid problems.  I have never tried to use `<` or `>` as part of the name, nor double quotes (e.g. escaping them with the `\` character)  I don't even know if this is allowed by the standard.

But, knowing that this **can be** actually an issue, why insisting in calling them starting with digits? As I'm assuming you are writing those files as application includes (and not system files) I assume you are free to select the name as you like, so then why the digits have specifically to be at the beginning of the name?  Why not to put them at the end, or in the middle? If you are to number them in some kind of sequence why not select a number base constituted only of letters (a base 26 numbering system, like, `A.h`, `B.h`, ..., `Z.h`, `AA.h`, `AB.h`, `AC.h`, ..., `AZ.h`, `BA.h`, `BB.h`, ..., `ZZ.h`, `AAA.h`, ...) or by digits represented by letters (in decimal, using A <-> 0, B <-> 1, ... J <-> 9, for example)

There's nothing that impedes you to name a file `>stdio.h<` on unix systems.  Should I have any problem to include it in my program with the following directive?

```
#include ">stdio.h<"
```

(just created these files and compiled them in an Ubuntu system with GCC)

#### file `>stdio.h<`

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

#### file `main.c`

```
#include ">stdio.h<"
/*        ^       ^  WTF!!!!!!!???? */
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world\n");
}
```

and the compilation:

```
$ make main
cc     main.c   -o main
$ _
```

and the run:

```
$ main
Hello, world
$ _
```

Can I do that? yes, but with all those programming styles you will get everybody confused, and nobody will want to maintain the code you write.